# Sprites break when floating parent container

Tags: sprite, break, floating

I'm using sprites for my navigation for this particular project. The sprites are working fine, and the original list items are floated left so that they stay in order. However, I'm trying to line it up with the right side of the page, not the left. I've tried to float the unordered list container to the right, the nav container and then a div outside of that and all of them break the sprite. Does anyone know why?

http://lrroberts0122.github.com/DWS/lab4/index.html

http://lrroberts0122.github.com/DWS/lab4/css/main.css

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding that I needed to float the h1 element left and give it a width of 340 and a height of 100 to match the other half. After that, the navigation floated in nicely.